# Amazon EC2 Instance free disk space discrepancy

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, diskspace

I have an Amazon EC2 m1.small instance (3.4.83-70.111.amzn1.i686).

I don't understand where is my free disk space.

What am I doing:

```
sudo su -
cd /
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  7.0G  864M  90% /
tmpfs           838M     0  838M   0% /dev/shm
```

Used: 7.0gb

```
du -sh /*

7.1M    /bin
24M     /boot
48K     /dev
6.7M    /etc
100K    /home
62M     /lib
4.0K    /local
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
208M    /opt
du: cannot access `/proc/29094/task/29094/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/29094/task/29094/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/29094/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/29094/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
1.5G    /root
9.9M    /sbin
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
48K     /tmp
704M    /usr
175M    /var
```

Total used: about 2697mb

7.0gb != 2697mb

Not even close.

The du output is right. I do actually have 1.5gb in /root, 208mb in /opt and so on. So this is the right numbers.

Where is other free space?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/209934/why-do-df-and-du-show-different-output suggests the discrepancy might be in open files, which are counted by df but not du.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Previously I looked for opened files only in /tmp.
But actually there were some in /opt/... with (deleted) mark

So Yes, That was the Problem.
Thank You.